# Fastify Swagger - Exclude certain routes

Tags: fastify

when using the @fastify-swagger plugin, is there an easy way to exclude certain routes via the @fastify-swagger options?

I know this can be done within the schema by specifing `hide: true`, but it would be useful to exclude routes by endpoints.